# Не двигается объект

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, разработка-игр

Почему не двигается кубик, при нажатие на клавиши ?

```js
var speedX = 0;
var speedY = 0;

const defSpeed = 5;

addEventListener('keydown', control, false);
addEventListener('keyup', stop, false);

function control(EO) {
  if (EO.keyCode === 38) {
    speedX = -defSpeed;
  }
  if (EO.keyCode === 40) {
    speedX = defSpeed;
  }
  if (EO.keyCode === 37) {
    speedY = -defSpeed;
  }
  if (EO.keyCode === 39) {
    speedY = defSpeed;
  }

}

function stop() {
  speedX = speedY = 0;
  return false;
}

function move() {
  alert("message?: DOMString")
  $("#player").css({
    top: "+=" + speedY,
    left: "+=" + speedX
  });
  requestAnimationFrame(move);
}
```

```css
#player {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 620px;
  left: 500px;
  background: red;
}

a {
  color: black;
}

a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="player"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: move разве где-то вызывается?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко, точно! Спасибо...

Comment: alert  не забудь убрать